# How do I fix content assistance with Eclipse + Robot Editor (RED) to suggest builtin keywords?

Tags: eclipse, robotframework

I have seen this problem on a Windows machine and also a Mac.  When I use Eclipse and RED to write .robot files, content assistance/auto completion does not work properly.  For example, if I enter "Run Keyword" then press Ctrl+Space, I receive no suggestions.  Eclipse+RED does not suggest standard library builtins:[image]

However, if I enter the first letters of a keyword I have written then press Ctrl+Space, suggestions are made:[image]

Has anybody else encountered this?  I have seen this on a Mac (Catalina 10.15.6) running Eclipse (2020-06 / 4.16.0) using the RED plugin (0.9.5) and Java Development Kit 14.0.1.  I have also seen this on a Windows10 machine running Eclipse (2019-12 / 4.14.0) using the RED plugin (0.9.3) and Java Runtime Environment 8, Update 241 (1.8.0_241).  It appears that keywords and global variables I've defined will be suggested, but no builtin keywords from the standard library or other libraries like Collections will be suggested...

Comment: Using windows 10, fresh install of Eclipse 2020-06 for Java developers and the RED plugin 0.9.5 I have no problem with autocomplete. Using Robot Framework 3.1.2 on Python 3.7.0 on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Eclipse for Committers... I will try the Java developers version.  Do you happen to know which java runtime environment you are using?

Comment: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem.  I was not creating new robot projects, I was opening existing folders but after doing so was not right clicking on the folder/project and selecting Robot Framework > Add Robot nature to the folder/project (so maybe no red.xml file was getting generated).
[image]

Before doing this the robot standard libraries and referenced libraries were not showing up at the top of the project explorer section of the folder.

[image]